Systemd CPUQuota for User Slice not working
I have a debian server, where I have placed the following limits in /etc/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/50-CPUQuota.conf
[Slice]
CPUQuota=600%
MemoryLimit=50G


The memory limits work perfectly for a user and the process is killed if anyone tries to use more than 50G RAM, however the CPUQuota does not. I see some programs executed by normal users taking up to 1200% or 1966% being shown in htop. Can anyone explain as to what is it that I am doing wrong? As I only want a single user to be able to use a maximum of 6 cpus and 50G on the server.

Default CPU Accounting was not turned on. This was discovered by
systemctl show -p DefaultCPUAccounting

DefaultCPUAccounting=no

This basically stops systemd from enforcing the user slice configuration of CPUQuota placed in
/etc/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/50-CPUQuota.conf 

of all login nodes.
To enable DefaultCPUAccounting, the option was uncommented in
/etc/systemd/system.conf

to
DefaultCPUAccounting=yes

Followed by
systemctl daemon-reload

Now, it works properly.
